# PHP : How to Insert Into single field?

Tags: php, mysql

i have some question about Mysql INSERT method.
i Have this command in my .php file :

```
<?php

include '../db/db.php';

$reps_list = $_POST['reps_list'];
$reps_list= json_decode($reps_list,TRUE);

foreach($reps_list['reps_list']['weight'] as $value){
    mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO reps (weight) VALUES(1)");
}

echo json_encode($reps_list);
mysqli_close ($conn);
```

?>

When i am running script nothing happens, no errors and no new data in my mysql database.

This is my database
[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you check for errors?

Comment: post full code...

Comment: Can you please share your code?

Comment: add "or die(mysqli_error($conn));" and see what you get

Comment: i have updated my code

Comment: @GiorgiAsaturyan If you add `var_dump($value);`, by example, inside the loop, do you have something printed? Maybe you loop over nothing?

Comment: Are the other columns which you aren't filling nullable?

Answer (score 0):

I have found my mistake, in the mysql field settings i have forgot to set "default" option.